# CSS spritesheet for images with a group of divs

Tags: css, performance, sprite-sheet

Im trying to use a spritesheet for a bunch of boxes, the way I am doing it obviously calls the image multiple times (causing the spritesheet to be useless, or actually worse).  Just wondering how I can make this more efficient calling the image once

```
<div class="live-box-outer">
                <div class="live-box contact-highlight" id="phone">

                    <div class="overlay" style="display: none">
                        <h2>
                            Telephone Number</h2>
                        <div class="arrow">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <span>Our #</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="live-box-outer">
                <div class="live-box" id="mobile">
                    <div class="overlay" style="display: none">
                        <h2>
                            text mobile
                            functions</h2>
                        <div class="arrow">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <span>Mobile Sites</span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And my style: (this is just a sample, I have about 9 boxes)

```
   #phone
{
     background-image:url('../img/Mountain.png');
     background-position: 0px 0;
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
}
#mobile
{

    background-image:url('../img/Mountain.png');
     background-position: 0px -134px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.live-box{
    background-image:url('../img/Mountain.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#phone
{
   background-position: 0px 0; 
}
#mobile
{
   background-position: 0px -134px;
}
```

Should work